# Bash automatic read

Tags: bash, shell, zip, arguments

First, I'm sorry for my poor english.

I'm working on a bash script which zip everyday a file. 
I must encrypt the zip with a password available in a file.

The script is called by another one launched, then I would like to launch a script like

myZipScript.sh fileToZip fileContainingThePassword

In my script I have

```
    password=${<$2}
    zip -e $password $1.zip $1
```

The problem is that the zip command will ask me two times a password. How to pass this password without a human intervention ?

Thx for all.

Answer (score 2):

I would skim through [man zip](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html) to see what options there are to pass passwords:

> -P password
>
> --password password
>
> Use password to encrypt zipfile entries (if any). THIS IS INSECURE! Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other user; even on stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking. Storing the plaintext password as part of a command line in an automated script is even worse. Whenever possible, use the non-echoing, interactive prompt to enter passwords. (And where security is truly important, use strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively weak standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.)

Answer (score 0):

apart from what Maxim said, the first line (storing the password in a variable) looks wrong.
i guess it really leaves the `$password` variable empty, thus `zip` wouldn't see it.

instead use

```
password=$(cat "$2")
zip -e -P "${password}" $1.zip $1
```

Comment: Assuming that `$2` is a file: `... -P "$(cat $password)" ...`